# creating database structure for Ecommece

Tags: mysql, database

I am confused about the size and color options in ecommerce products table./
You might have seen options in clothing e commerce website when we go to add to cart option for any cloth e.g shirt it asks for size and color and show results simultaneously if that size or color is available or not.

How can i achive this? I have a product table having common fields like id, name, image, category id, subcategory id, details etc... Should size and color be in it ?

Problem is that if sizes can vary in units as well like for clothes its usually M,L,XL but what if a customer went to a  TV page it should have inches there...

I hope i've described it clear

Please provide some good opinion

Thanks

Comment: in short you should learn normalization. I suggest to use different table to store the colors, size and linked them with product category. It might be good also to put active column for reference that color/size is available

Answer (score 1):

You'd have something like this, I think (PKs in asterisks)

```
Products ( *ProductId, Name, Description )
Skus ( ProductId, *SkuId, Name )
Options ( *OptionId, Name, Value )
SkuOptions ( *SkuId, OptionId )
```

(and an optional `Categories` table if you think you need that)

This is what the data would look like:

#### Products

```
1, 'Sharp Aquous TV', 'LED backlit TV in a variety of sizes'
2, 'Sony Bravia TV', 'LED backlit TV in a single size'
```

#### Options

```
1, 'Size', '60 inches'
2, 'Size', '70 inches'
3, 'Size', '80 inches'
4, 'Colour', 'Black'
5, 'Colour', 'Silver'
```

#### Skus

```
1, 'LC-60LE857U', 'Sharp Aquous 60 inches'
1, 'LC-70LE857U', 'Sharp Aquous 70 inches'
1, 'LC-80LE857U', 'Sharp Aquous 80 inches'
2, 'KDL-70R550A', 'Sony Bravia 70 inches'
```

#### SkuOptions

```
'LC-60LE857U', 1
'LC-60LE857U', 4
'LC-70LE857U', 2
'LC-70LE857U', 4
'LC-80LE857U', 3
'LC-80LE857U', 4
'KDL-70R550A', 2
'KDL-70R550A', 5
```

Queries for this data is an exercise left up to the reader :)

Comment: An SKU is a "Stock Keeping Unit" - the irreducible unit of retail. Each variation on a product, such as a color or size is its own SKU (e.g. a Black, 60 inch Sony Bravia has a different SKU to a White, 60 inch Sony Bravia). You'll need a table for those, hence why it's in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Understand it so -

1. Product is something listed, but not sold.
2. A product has attributes.
3. When all attributes are chosen, you sell it and call it a SKU , i.e Stock Keeping Unit.

Eg: 
Levis Jeans is a product.
Waist, Length, Color, Stitch are the attributes.
Levis Jeans, W32, L34, Blue, Regular Fit is a SKU.

These are all stored in different tables and related based on keys.

Good day!
Enjoy your e-Comm design experience.

Ganesh